# Nestjs modules - shared custom provider is not working

Tags: nestjs

I have a proyect with multiple modules, and all of them need the same provider, then I have used a shared module but I don't know where the mistake is

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ChatBot } from './chat-bot';
import { ChatBotImplementation } from './chat-bot.implementation';

@Module({
  providers: [{ provide: ChatBot, useClass: ChatBotImplementation }],
  exports: [ChatBot],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CoreService } from './core.service';

@Module({
  providers: [CoreService],
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';

@Module({
  imports: [SharedModule, CoreModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ChatBot } from 'src/shared/chat-bot';

@Injectable()
export class CoreService {
  constructor(chatBot: ChatBot) {
    chatBot.send('hola');
  }
}
```

When I start the server, it throws this error:

```
[Nest] 8456  - 29/12/2022, 17:21:08   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CoreService (?). Please make sure that the argument ChatBot at index [0] is available in the CoreModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is CoreModule a valid NestJS module?
- If ChatBot is a provider, is it part of the current CoreModule?
- If ChatBot is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within CoreModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ChatBot */ ]
  })
```

ChatBot is an abstract class and ChatBotImplementation implements ChatBot abstract class, I have tried with symbol as provide but it don't working either. If I put the provider in the same module that use it then it works, I supose that the misteka should be in the, exports part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CoreModule` doesn't have the `SharedModule` in its `imports` so it doesn't have access to providers from the `SharedModule`'s `exports`. Add `imports: [SharedModule]` to the `CoreModule`'s module metadata and you'll be good to go